# blank to numeric conversion derived column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a source column with blank (not "NULL"), and target as numeric. while converting using the data conversion it is not converting due to balnk source value so I used derived column to replace a blank value with NULL or 0 as

(source column == " ") ? "0" : source column

but its not giving the value as 0 in the blank place.

thanks
prav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
(LEN(TRIM(sourceColumn)) = 0 ? "0" : sourceColumn)
```

Comment: Thanks Barry, The logic worked for my data. it is also working with RTRIM instead of TRIM. thanks prav

Answer (score 0):

```
([source column] == null || [source column].TrimEnd().Length == 0)
     ? "0"
     : [source column]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the codingbadger answer is missing 1 =. I used that answer but to make it valid I had to write it as:

```
(LEN(TRIM(sourceColumn)) == 0 ? "0" : sourceColumn)
```